Post docker.container.logs asynchronous as SSE using fast-api and docker
I am trying to create an API that can fetch logs from a docker container and returns them as an event-stream.
I use python as language together with the fastapi and docker package.
Whenever I try to test my endpoint with postman I only get the connection response but no additional responses of data. But I receive the logs as console output in python.
The endpoint:
@app.get("/servers/{server_id}/logs")
async def get_logs(server_id: str):
    print("Endpoint /logs reached")
    return StreamingResponse(get_server_logs(server_id), media_type="text/event-stream")

The log_handling:
def get_server_logs(server_id: str):
    try:
        container = client.containers.get(server_id)

        for log in container.logs(stream=True, follow=True, tail=10):
            cleaned_log = log.decode("utf-8").strip()
            print(cleaned_log)
            yield f'data: {cleaned_log}\n\n'

    except DockerException as e:
        yield handle_docker_exception(e)

    except Exception as e:
        yield f'data: An error occurred: {str(e)}\n\n'

The Docker SDK docs state that the container.logs call returns a blocking generator which, I think, is the cause of my API not processing any other request while the event-stream is open. (This also includes posting the logs as a response)
So I got it working on the log posting part but it does not closes the connection properly and also doesn't handle other requests parallel in Postman. (Don't know if that is a limitation of Postman)
The endpoint:
@app.get("/servers/{server_id}/logs")
async def get_logs(server_id: str):
    print("Endpoint /logs reached")
    return StreamingResponse(get_server_logs(server_id), media_type="text/event-stream")

Async generator:
async def get_server_logs(server_id: str, request: Request):
    try:
        container = client.containers.get(server_id)
        async for log in async_logs_generator(container, follow=True, tail=10):
            cleaned_log = log.decode("utf-8").strip()
            print(cleaned_log)
            yield f'data: {cleaned_log}\n\n'

    except DockerException as e:
        yield handle_docker_exception(e)

    except Exception as e:
        yield f'data: An error occurred: {str(e)}\n\n'

Parallel thread:
# Runs the blocking container.logs() call in a seperate thread
def run_blocking_logs_in_thread(container, **kwargs):
    queue = Queue()

    def worker():
        try:
            for log in container.logs(stream=True, **kwargs):
                queue.put(log)
        except Exception as e:
            queue.put(e)
        finally:
            queue.put(None)  # Signal the end of the logs

    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    thread.start()

    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        if isinstance(item, Exception):
            raise item
        yield item

    thread.join()

